# How to display all the properties of an object from an array of objects in javascript?

Tags: javascript, json

I am new to javascript.I have been working on a program where I use a json dataset in javascript by assigning it to a variable.The link of the dataset is below.
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Biuni/PokemonGO-Pokedex/master/pokedex.json

I have to write a function where I take a pokemon's name as input and display all its details.Below is the function I used.

```
var list=pokeDex.pokemon;
var name=prompt("Enter the name of a pokemon");
// Function  taking pokemon’s name as argument and displaying the 
information of that pokemon.
function displayInfo(name)
 {
  for(var items in list)
  {
   if (name==list[items].name)
   {
   console.log(list[items]);
   break;
    }

    else
    {
    //alert("error");

    }
   }
  }
```

The function seems to be working properly for all the pokemons in the list only if the alert statement in else block is a comment.Otherwise the function displays error for all the pokemons except the first one in the dataset.

Comment: can you also post the list of pokemon?

Comment: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Biuni/PokemonGO-Pokedex/master/pokedex.json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi simplify your logic by filtering by name, there are high order functions like `filter` that iterate through arrays and gets the one that returns true to your condition, in this case, the condition would be the pokemon name. Also when matching strings it's interesting to apply lowercase to match regardless of uppercase or lowercase letters

Code could look like the following:

```
const list = pokeDex.pokemon
const inputName = prompt("Enter the name of a pokemon")
const [ pokemonSelected ] = list.filter(pokemon => pokemon.name.toLowerCase() === inputName.toLowerCase())
console.log(pokemonSelected)
```

I've made a small JSfiddle for you: https://jsfiddle.net/t8uep0ga/10/
Open your console and check the console.log()! Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can easily simplyfy your logic to

```
function displayInfo(searchName)
 {
  const filteredList = list.filter(poke => poke.name==searchName)
   if (filteredList > 0)
   {
   console.log(filteredList[0]);
    }
    else
    {
    alert("error");
    }
  }
```

This will first iterate through list and search for the `pokemon` with `searchName`

In your code it tries to give error alert on if first one is not the searchPokemon i.e.else block without even searching in rest of list.

Comment: It worked after adding length property to filteredList,i.e,if(filteredList.length >0).

Comment: great (Y). it was just a typo from my side. :)